# What is the synonym for "describe in writing"?

Tags: synonyms, word-in-context

How do you say in English to describe something that is in writing?

For example, I'm walking in a big office building and I notice that some of the rooms are having a writing above their doors which tells what kind of a room this is. The writing is not a plaque or a label of any kind. It's just written on a wall above a door with paint.

def for the word "depict" (source TFD):

> **2.** *to represent in words; describe*

What would I say to my companion if I were in this building with him. "Look the rooms are depicted above the doors"? If yes, can you provide some additional synonyms if there are any?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say, "*The rooms are **labelled/marked/named** above the doors*".

To "describe" the rooms would mean a phrase or more about the rooms, rather than just the label, such as, "a room for holding meetings with up to 16 people".

To "depict" the rooms would mean to describe what the rooms look like, which again, would be a phrase or more, such as, "*a narrow, light brown room with a long table and 16 chairs, and a long window that looks over the lake*".

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies alot. So the word labeled doesn't require there to be "a label" (a piece of plastic or paper containing description which you stick to something) Can it be just  a writting on a wall?

Comment: Correct. The word "label" has more than one definition. It could be a physical label, the name something has, the act of assigning a name to something, or *the act of identifying something by its name*.

Comment: So when I see something written explicitly on a wall can I say "this wall is labeled so and so"? or can " look there is a label on that wall"?

Comment: Yes to "this wall is labelled", but no to "there's a label". The paint on the wall is not a label. I can't think of a good word to replace "label" in your second example, but it's not "label". A physical label is usually a cloth or paper tag, or something similar. "Sign" would be closer, but we also don't think of paint on a wall as a sign.

Comment: description perhaps?

Comment: @StaticBounce Your question was about what *verb* to use in the sentence, "Look the rooms are _________ above the doors". "Description" is a noun. "Described" doesn't fit for the reasons in my answer.

Comment: Just randomly came upon a definiton in yourfreedictionary.com for the word "describe" that i missed during my research when writing this post.                                                               
Describe:To picture in words.